# Unable to find availability zone of a running, azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

With Azure Python SDK, one can query Virtual Machine data using ComputeManagementClient
But I haven't found out how to find the zone of a running VM.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python

`compute_client.virtual_machines.instance_view(resource['ResourceGroupName'],resource['ResourceName'])`

does not have zone information

and `compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource['ResourceGroupName'],resource['ResourceName'])
has list of zones which always return Null.`

Comment: well, is the vm actually zone pinned? because if its not - it would not have a zone property populated with anything

Comment: Even if it is not, the vm must be running in one of the Azure Availability zones 1, 2 or 3, SEE: instance metadata does have this information but I can not use that externally because my calls are from outside VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service

Comment: if its not vm pinned it wouldn't have a zone property in azure api (or it would be blank, what you are seeing)

Comment: What zone information do you want to get from the VM?

Comment: I see blank, want to know which physical AZ it is running in,

Comment: @am5 did you figure out a way to solve this issue?